# xmlHttp.status==200 is never true

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a project and I'm using ajax and php. The problem is that the status of the XMLHttpRequest() is never 200. None of the solutions I've searched is working so I'm asking here. I copy/paste here the script and the php file which ajax sends a variable.
**The script**

```
function categoryfilter(int) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 $$ xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
            alert("GOOD");
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET","ajax_livecategorysearch.php?category=" + int, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

**The php file**

> `<?php echo "whatever"; ?>`

**The html code**

```
<input id="category" name="category" type="radio" checked="checked" onclick="categoryfilter(this.value);" >
```

When I delete the condition xmlHttp.status==200, the function returns error 404 page not found.

Comment: I believe `$$` should be `&&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the code:

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 $$ xmlHttp.status==200)
```

should be

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
```

Comment: The problem probably is on server side or you are accessing a wrong url. Try to access the URL simply from browser. Does it work?

Comment: True story my friend, that was the problem with the url. Thank you very much.